# how to make document.write to write in a specific html tag instead of writing anywhere?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this 2D array in JavaScript and trying to print its elements using innerHTML or document.write, but using innerHTML in a for loop overrides all elements on each other. using document.write puts all elements in a row (which I don't more than 3 elements in a row), so please help me find a way! (I know my solution is super wrong, but I'm just trying to show what I'm thinking of)

```
const myData = function(){
return
[[{"number":1,"name":"Jack","day":"Sat"},
  {"number":2,"name":"Max","day":"Sun"}],
  [{"number":3,"name":"Al","day":"Mon"},
   {"number":4,"name":"Jacky","day":"Tues"}
   {"number":5,"name":"Daniel","day":"Wed"}]];
};

var array = myData();
var len = array.length;
var i, j;
for (i=0; i<len; i++){
  for (j=0; j<3; j++){
    document.getElementByID(demo).innerHTML = array[i][j].number;
    document.getElementByID(demo).innerHTML = array[i][j].day;
    document.getElementByID(demo).innerHTML = array[i][j].name;
```

}
}

Comment: What do you mean by “overrides all elements on each other”? Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: You should get into the practice of never using `document.write()`. You get the Element in a number of ways, perhaps the most common is `var yourElement = document.getElementById('yourElementId');`. For assignment on most anything but an input it's like `yourElement.innerHTML = 'some text value here';`... for an input it's like `yourElement.value = 'some text value here';`. Make sure you use the proper HTML entities on innerHTML.

Comment: can you show us your attempt at the loop you mentioned as well at your html? you can edit your post and put a code snippet in.

Comment: Just added my solution which is far far away from being a correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the innerHTML, so it will have the old value and the new one too.

just put a + before the =:

```
document.getElementByID(demo).innerHTML += array[i][j].number;
document.getElementByID(demo).innerHTML += array[i][j].day;
document.getElementByID(demo).innerHTML += array[i][j].name;
```